# Webapi endpoint with one database call is slow opposed to others

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I'm facing a very strange behavior on my project.

I have an endpoint which basically does one call/query to the database and return that data as JSON.

The issue I have is regarding performance. Using fiddler I call that endpoint and I get a reply on 250ms average.

However something happens that after some time it suddenly becomes very slow and takes around 22 seconds every time and does not get back.

The strange thing here is that when I run the query that EF generates directly using Sql Server Management Studio (I got the query using SQL Profiler) it's instantaneous always no matter what.

It's important to say that all other endpoints work as expected, I don't see anything special going on there regarding performance. They basically always take the some time roughly.

Everytime I redeploy the cloud app (It's hosted on azure) the issue goes away apparently, but I cannot tell for sure since I'm not able to deploy it to production that often.

Things that I found out meanwhile :

- Running it locally and pointing to the production database I get an average of about 500ms and never got anything above 1 second.
- It's noticeable that there is a pattern between the number of records and the slowliness. With 90 rows returned I was getting 12 seconds, now with 150 rows I'm getting 22 seconds.

Thanks a lot for any help,